# cuda thrust::remove_if throws "thrust::system::system_error" for device_vector?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am currently using CUDA 7.5 under VS 2013.
Today I needed to remove some of the elements from a `device_vector`, thus decided to use `remove_if`. But however I modify the code, the program just compiles well but throws "thrust::system::system_error" at run time.

Firstly I tried my own code:

```
int main()
{
    thrust::host_vector<int> AA(10, 1);
    thrust::sequence(AA.begin(), AA.end());
    thrust::host_vector<bool> SS(10,false);
    thrust::fill(SS.begin(), SS.begin() + 5, true);
    thrust::device_vector<int> devAA=AA;
    thrust::device_vector<bool> devSS = SS;
    thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator new_end = thrust::remove_if(thrust::device,
    devAA.begin(), devAA.end(), devSS.begin(), thrust::identity<int>());
}
```

But it throws `thrust::system::system_error` at run time. However, if I use two `host_vector`, i.e. `AA` and `SS` to perform `remove_if`, everything goes fine.

Then, I tried the code I found on [stackoverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17595078/4503060), the code in Robert Crovella's answer seemed work fine, but on my machine, it still throws `thrust::system::system_error`.

Did new version of thrust modify anything? Or I should try some other way? I am using cmake to organise the code, is there any thing special?

Comment: Could you explain your problem a little better? Is the code you have posted working for you or not? When you say " However, if I use two host_vector, i.e. AA and SS to perform remove_if, everything goes fine" what does that mean relative to the code you have posted?

Comment: I don't have any trouble with what you have posted.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/GG10n8ZV) is my test case.  You might have a problem with your machine setup or CUDA install.

Comment: @talonmies The original code I posted here doesn't work. It only works if I modify the last line to  ` thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator new_end = thrust::remove_if( AA.begin(), AA.end(), SS.begin(), hrust::identity<int>()); `

Comment: @RobertCrovella I tried to reinstall CUDA 7.5 but the problem still exists. Then I tested the code using CUDA 6.5 and everything was fine ...

Comment: I was able to compile and run successfully the code I posted [here](http://pastebin.com/GG10n8ZV) on windows 7 64-bit, CUDA 7.5, VS 2013, on a GTX460M and compiling for `compute_20,sm_20`.  So I think your code works fine, but you have a problem with machine setup.  It's probably going to be hard to diagnose with the information you've provided.  What GPU are you trying to run this code on?  What GPU architecture are you compiling for?  In my test, if I compile for an incorrect architecture (for example `compute_30,sm_30`) then thrust will throw an error.

Comment: If you add precise thrust error checking like [this](http://pastebin.com/QzLvBfpk), then it's likely you'll get more information about why the system error is occurring.  For example, if I compile that code for `compute_30,sm_30` but run on my cc2.0 device, I get the following: "thrust system error: cudaFuncGetAttributes in function_attributes: invalid device function" and the "invalid device function" message is a good indicator that I have compiled for an incorrect GPU type.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I am using GT750M and I tried your code with both `compute_20,sm_20` and `compute_30,sm_30`, debug and release ... I posted my project file [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8sQu-AMc84hbkJFUXBRUFIySWs/view?usp=sharing), would you please try it on your machine ?

Comment: What was the actual printout when you ran [this](http://pastebin.com/QzLvBfpk) ?

Comment: I opened your project file.  Are you building a Win32 project?  You should be building a x64 release project.  Anyway, I don't have any trouble building and running your project on my machine if I build an x64 release project.  Yes, if you build a win32 project it will not work.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Hell yes! I changed to x64 and everything was find! Why are you so awesome !

Comment: @RobertCrovella In fact, I've never noticed it is not allowed to run a 32-bit program with thrust on a x64 OS.

Comment: Official support for 32-bit is disappearing in newer CUDA versions.  In CUDA 7.5 it is almost gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that OP was building a 32-bit project.  The issue was resolved when switching to a 64-bit project.

My recommendation for CUDA 7.5 and beyond is to only use 64-bit projects.  If you review the current state of 32-bit support on [windows](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#x86-32-bit-support) and [linux](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#x86-32-bit-support) you'll find it's quite limited.

Purely as a matter of conjecture, this issue may be related to [thrust issue #715](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/715)