# CUDA thrust - nothing works

Tags: cuda, thrust

My CUDA project already has few kernels that work properly, but I just can't get thrust to work. 
I tried running some trivial examples I've found on the net but nothing works. 
I always get an exception from this fragment of CUDA's code

```
  inline void checked_cudaMemcpyAsync(void *dst, const void *src, size_t count, enum cudaMemcpyKind kind, cudaStream_t stream)
  {
  cudaError_t error = cudaMemcpyAsync(dst,src,count,kind,stream);
  if(error)
  {
    throw thrust::system_error(error, thrust::cuda_category());
  } // end error
  } // end checked_cudaMemcpy()
```

Value of `error` is `cudaErrorInvalidValue`

Example code I tried running:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

int main()
{
    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(1 << 10);
    thrust::generate(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), rand);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec = h_vec;
    thrust::sort(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end());
    thrust::copy(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), h_vec.begin());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: which CUDA version? which thrust version? which GPU? which driver?

Comment: sm_30, GTX 770, win 8.1, driver 358.91, cuda 7.5.17, THRUST_VERSION 100802

Comment: Are you sure you are building a 64 bit project in release mode?

Comment: this may be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460690/thrustcopy-doesnt-work-for-device-vectors) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000054/cuda-thrustremove-if-throws-thrustsystemsystem-error-for-device-vector), in particular building a win32 VS project vs. building a x64 VS project.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you. Also had to remove -G flag. Do you perhaps know why is there a problem with x86 executables? And why does it allow to be compiled in 32 bit when it is not supposed to work like that?

Comment: I don't have a great answer for you.  If you read the linked questions, answers and comments, you'll discover that there is evidence that support for 32-bit in CUDA is gradually being removed.  One comment even suggested an issue with ordinary (non-thrust) CUDA code in 32-bit.  Thus my suggestion to compile a x64 app.  You're welcome to file thrust issues or bugs at developer.nvidia.com.

Comment: I would generally consider this and the other two linked questions to be duplicates of thrust [issue #715](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/715), which is currently recorded as a bug in thrust.  But I don't know root cause, nor do I have much understanding of the issue anyway.  Personally I couldn't rule out  the possibility that there is an underlying CUDA issue, but it may be limited to thrust.

Comment: with respect to the `-G` compiler switch, that has been a [documented concern with thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Debugging) for some time.